# CakePHP link to login page redirect problems

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, authentication

I am trying to create a very simple link that will send the users to the login page. Here is the code for my link:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Login', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

That works fine, the user is sent to the login page, however the problem is that once the user has logged in they are being directed back to the login page!

I understand the problem is that cakePHP automatically redirects the user to the last page, which is a good thing in the example that a user tried to access a page without being logged in, and then once they login it redirects them to that page. But how to I create a simple link to the login page that redirects after they login, to the page they were on when they clicked the login link?

this is my login function:

```
public function login() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    $returned = $this->Session->read('referedLogin');
                        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($this->Session->read('referedLogin')));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->write('referedLogin', $this->referer());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `loginRedirect` link in **AppController**

```
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
                'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'User', 'action'=>'login'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('contoller'=>'User', 'action'=>'login'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'User', 'action'=>'logout'),
                ..............................................
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the target URL into Session:

```
Auth.redirect
```

Then user will be redirected to that URL.

Comment: I editied my login function above to save the refered url to the session, now when a user logs in from the login link it redirects correctly, but if they are redirected to the login page because they tried to access a page that can only be view after login, the redirection is broken (it redirects to '/', and not the page they tried to access)

Comment: It depends how did you edit your function. Another way is to store a link encoded as URL param and perform redirection based on this param presence.

Comment: I edited my question with the changes I made to the login function. I added do a Session->write to store the referer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. But why don't you clear _referedLogin_ after redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code might resolve your problem,

In the login action add the following code,

```
if(!empty($this->Auth->user) {
 $controller = $this->params['controller'];
 $action = $this->params['action'];
 return $this->redirect(array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action));
}
```